# Convert a double to 2 decimal places with comma separator

Tags: java, vaadin7

In my view i have the below code

```
IndexedContainer icLoaded = new IndexedContainer(); 
icLoaded.removeAllItems();  
icLoaded.removeAllContainerFilters();

icLoaded.addContainerProperty("Average Cost", Double.class, null);
```

In the model i have the below code

```
public IndexedContainer DoFetchstockCodesTable(String passedSQL,
        IndexedContainer passTable, String CustomsaleQuerry) {

    try {

        Class.forName(dbsettings.dbDriver);

        final Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                new Home().GiveMeSessionDB(), dbsettings.dbUsername,
                dbsettings.dbPassword);
        final Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(passedSQL.trim());

        while (rs.next()) {

            passTable.addItem(rs.getString("item_id"));

            passTable.getContainerProperty(rs.getString("item_id"),
                    "Average Cost").setValue(rs.getDouble("average_cost"));
```

How can i convert the below

```
 passTable.getContainerProperty(rs.getString("item_id"),
                    "Average Cost").setValue(rs.getDouble("average_cost"));
```

to display a number with 2 decimal places separated by a comma separator like 1,000.12 using

```
 NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
```

When i use the below , nothing gets displayed .

```
 passTable.getContainerProperty(rs.getString("item_id"),
                    "Average Cost").setValue(numberFormat.format(rs.getDouble("average_cost")));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You call [`NumberFormat#format(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format%28double%29) and save the formatted `double` as a `String`, because a `double` is a primitive value and it has no inherent formatting -

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
double val = 1000.12;
System.out.println(numberFormat.format(val));
```

Output is

```
1,000.12
```

**Edit**

You need to change this

```
icLoaded.addContainerProperty("Average Cost", Double.class, null);
```

to

```
icLoaded.addContainerProperty("Average Cost", String.class, null);
```

Comment: Thanks @Elliott.I am able to convert as above, i have change to     double averageCost = rs.getDouble("average_cost");
    passTable.getContainerProperty(rs.getString("item_id"),
      "Average Cost").setValue(numberFormat.format(averageCost)); and still no display. Note am using vaadin 7

Comment: I'm going to guess that `passTable.getContainerProperty(rs.getString("item_id"), "Average Cost").` isn't returning what you think it is.

Comment: Note without converting to numberFormat.format(averageCost)) it displays the unformatted data i.e passTable.getContainerProperty(rs.getString("item_id"), Average Cost").setValue(rs.getDouble("average_cost"));

Comment: @pmaingi Edited my answer. You set that to a `double` in `icLoaded`.

Comment: Thanks alot @Elliot , i have changed to String.class and its now working

Answer (score 2):

You can format the value in this way:

```
Table table = new Table() {
    @Override
    protected String formatPropertyValue(Object rowId, Object colId, Property<?> property) {
        if ("Average Cost".equals(colId)) {
            NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
            return numberFormat.format(property.getValue());
        }
        return super.formatPropertyValue(rowId, colId, property);
    }
}
```